# WooCommerce: How to get all categories for current product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to get or list all category names or IDs of the current product in WooCommerce.
Using this code: I get whole **links** to the categories but I want their names or IDs.

```
<?php
    // Get list of ALL categories for current product
    $cats = wc_get_product_category_list( $id );

    var_dump($cats);
?>
```

I want categories' **names** or **IDs** so I can use them to iterate through.

Answer (score 2):

Pase the following code in the `functions.php` file of the theme.

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    $categories = wp_get_post_terms( 17, 'product_cat' );
    if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
        $html = '<ul>';
        foreach( $categories as $category ) {
            $html .= "<li>{$category->name}</li>";
        }
        $html .= '</ul>';
    }

    echo $html;
    die;
});
```

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/

Answer (score 1):

```
// Get list of ALL categories for current product
$term_ids = array();
$terms = get_the_terms( 158, "product_cat" );
if(!is_wp_error( $terms )){
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $term_ids[] = $term->term_id;
    }
}

var_dump($term_ids);exit;
```

Try this